# Generates parse input error in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

The below code sequence is generating a parse error on input `|`. 
If the input was a leaf node then call leafFunc with value
If the input was a tree node then call TreeFunc with left Subtree,value,right Subtree

```
data Tree t = Leaf t
        | Node (Tree t) t (Tree t)

foldTree :: (t1 -> t -> t1 -> t1) -> (t -> t1) -> Tree t -> t1
foldTree treeFn leafFn tree= | foldTree (Leaf v) = leafFn(v)
                             | foldTree (Node left v right) = treeFn(left v right)


Input : foldTree (\t1 t t2->t1 + 5*t + t2) (\x->x+9) (Leaf 5)
Expected Output : 14

Input : foldTree (\t1 t t2->t1 + 3*t + t2) (\x->x+5) (Tree (Leaf 3) 2 (Leaf 4))
Expected Output : 23
```

I am a newbie in haskell.

Comment: The parse error results form your guard statement being incorrectly formatted. You shouldn't place an equal sign before `|`. You have some other things to deal fix after that, including applying foldTree with the correct number of arguments within the guards.

Comment: I want to pattern match after the "=" . How can I do that ? :) TIA

Comment: You're confusing function/guard syntax. To the right of the guard, you include predicates (functions that evaluation to `True` or `False`) and the corresponding value assignments. If you want to pattern match different cases (leaf vs. node), you can do so with a case statement or by manually matching several cases with function declarations. I recommend you read this: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions

Answer (score 1):

```
data Tree t = Leaf t
              | Node (Tree t) t (Tree t)

foldTree :: (Tree t -> t -> Tree t -> t1) -> (t -> t1) -> Tree t -> t1
foldTree treeFn leafFn (Leaf v) = leafFn v
foldTree treeFn leafFn (Node left v right) = treeFn left v right
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is what you want

```
data Tree t = Leaf t | Node (Tree t) t (Tree t) deriving Show

foldTree :: (t1 -> t -> t1 -> t1) -> (t -> t1) -> Tree t -> t1
foldTree treeFn leafFn tree 
                | foldTree (Leaf v) = leafFn v
                | foldTree (Node left v right) = treeFn left v right
```